# How can I delete cookies for one site in Safari, without deleting local data?

Tags: safari, cookies

I'm having trouble logging in to a website in Safari, so I wanted to delete cookies for that one site. I went to **Safari > Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data** And searches for the site's name, but I see that the site is using cookies *and* local storage. I don't want to delete the local storage, just the *cookies*.

[image: Screenshot of Safari Privacy preferences showing site in question]

This is on Mac OS X 10.15.7 with Safari version 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610)

In Safari, How can I delete just the cookies for a single site and leave the local data?

Comment: Is Safari Required?  Firefox and (gack!) Chrome have add-ons that allow you to manipulate individual Cookies the way you're describing.

Comment: For this question, yes, because I already know how to do it in Chrome 

Comment: Got it...I was just looking for a way to solve the immediate problem...I'm not a frequent Safari user.  Most of the time it's for downloading other browsers and for testing a website for functionality.

Comment: Thanks @Allan! Yeah for now I just cleared all the data, including local storage, but that caused me to lose some preferences so I was looking for a better fix _specifically for Safari_. But the immediate issue is "solved", for various definitions of solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit the website, open the developer tools (option-cmd-i, enabled in Preferences → Advanced), choose the Storage tab, then Cookies in the sidebar, and for each cookie, select it in the list and press backspace.